# How do I subtract items that are in my inventory and print them later in my program?

Tags: python

I have a program that totally works except I have to have it report how many item are left in inventory after the user "checkout" (option 2). I have created a function called inhand. In this function I assigned each item in inventory with the qty of 100. The following line is suppose to take the item the user selected and subtract the qty they entered. After the user chooses option 2 "checkout". It prints a "bill". I want it to print how many of each item is left in inventory. Instead it currently errors. How do I fix this?

Full Code:

```
#DEFINING EACH RETAIL ITEM TEMPLATE

class RetailItem:
    def __init__(self,desc,unit,price):
        self.description = desc
        self.units = unit
        self.price = price

#CREATING WHERE SELECTED ITEMS WITH RESIDE
class CashRegister:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shopping_list=[]
    def purchase_item(self,retail):
        #adding item to list
        self.shopping_list.append(retail)
#CREATING PRICING / COST
    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for i in self.shopping_list:
            total+=(i.units*i.price)
        return total
#HOW THE CHECKOUT WILL FORMAT/LOOK IN AFFECT ON OPTION 2 (CHECKOUT)
    def show_items(self):
        if not self.shopping_list:
            return
        print("{:<15}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}".format(" "*9,"Description","Units","Price"))
        print("-"*75)
        for c,i in enumerate(self.shopping_list,1):
            print("{:<15}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}".format("Item #"+str(c),i.description,i.units,i.price))
        print("-"*75)

    def inhand():
        inventory = { "Pants":100, "Shirt":100, "Dress":100, "Socks":100, "Sweater":100 }
        inventory[item_type] -= qty_purchased
        
def main():
    #ADDING TO CART
    c=CashRegister()
    #MENU
    
    while 1:
        try:
            print("1. Purchase\n2. Checkout\n3. Clear\n4. Exit")
            print()
            choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
            print()
            if choice == 1:
                while 1:
                    print()
                    print("Menu\n-----------------------\n1. Pants\n2. Shirt\n3. Dress\n4. Socks\n5. Sweater")
                    item_type = int(input("Select item: "))
                    print()
                    qty=int(input("Enter quantity: "))
                    #ITEMS TO CHOOSE FROM AND ADD TO CART
                    if item_type == 1:
                        c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Pants",qty,44.95))
                    elif item_type == 2:
                        c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Shirt",qty,34.95))
                    elif item_type == 3:
                        c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Dress",qty,79.95))
                    elif item_type == 4:
                        c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Socks",qty,6.95))
                    elif item_type == 5:
                        c.purchase_item(RetailItem("Sweater",qty,24.95))
                    else:
                        #ERROR MESSAGE
                        print("Invalid item! try again")
                        print()
                        continue
                    print("Item added to list")
                    print()
                    break
            elif choice == 2:
                if not c.shopping_list:
                    #ERROR MESSAGE
                    print("Nothing to checkout!")
                    print()
                    continue
                #DISPLAYING BILL
                c.show_items()
                print(" "*60+"Total: ${}".format(round(c.get_total(),2)))
                print()
                print(inhand)
            elif choice == 3:
                #CLEARING
                c.shopping_list=[]
            elif choice == 4:
                #EXIT
                exit()
            else:
                #ERROR MESSAGE
                print("Invalid choice! try again!")
            print()
            #ERROR MESSAGE
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))
            print()

#RUN PROGRAM
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback, as that will tell where the error is occurring

Comment: you did not declare item_type and qty_purchased yet in ` inventory[item_type] -= qty_purchased`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must declare that `inhand` function scope variable first as well making the function accessible throughout the class, then assign `inventory` to your class variable otherwise it wont get stored globally in your class (only inside of your function) for example:

```
def inhand(self,item_type,qty_purchased):
    self.inventory = { "Pants":100, "Shirt":100, "Dress":100, "Socks":100, "Sweater":100 }
    self.inventory[item_type] -= qty_purchased
```

so then you can use it repetitively using for loop

```
self.item_type_qty[["Pants",20],["Dress",20]] #for example, this variable store user picked item
for x in self.item_type_qty:
    self.inhand(x[0],x[1]) #calling inhand function repetitively
```

you will also need to validate if in case those inventory get valued below zero. which at this point you can figure it out on your own. good luck

Comment: I wasnt doing it like that. -1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the inventory in the constructor. Let the `inhand` function check the inventory and return True\False if the purchase can be made.

Try this code:

```
#CREATING WHERE SELECTED ITEMS WITH RESIDE
class CashRegister:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shopping_list=[]
        self.inventory = { "Pants":100, "Shirt":100, "Dress":100, "Socks":100, "Sweater":100 }
        
    def purchase_item(self,retail):
        #adding item to list
        if self.inhand(retail.description, retail.units):
           self.shopping_list.append(retail)
        
#CREATING PRICING / COST
    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for i in self.shopping_list:
            total+=(i.units*i.price)
        return total
#HOW THE CHECKOUT WILL FORMAT/LOOK IN AFFECT ON OPTION 2 (CHECKOUT)
    def show_items(self):
        if not self.shopping_list:
            return
        print("{:<15}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}".format(" "*9,"Description","Units","Price"))
        print("-"*75)
        for c,i in enumerate(self.shopping_list,1):
            print("{:<15}{:<25}{:<25}{:<10}".format("Item #"+str(c),i.description,i.units,i.price))
        print("-"*75)
        
    def inhand(self,item_type,qty_purchased):
        if self.inventory[item_type] < qty_purchased:
           print(f"Cannot purchase {qty_purchased} {item_type}. Only {self.inventory[item_type]} left in stock.")
           return False
        self.inventory[item_type] -= qty_purchased
        return True
```

You can print the inventory after printing the cart:

```
 #DISPLAYING BILL
 c.show_items()
 print(" "*60+"Total: ${}".format(round(c.get_total(),2)))
 print()
 print(">> Inventory:", c.inventory)
```